# OVH server DDOS attack protection

Tags: windows, ddos, udp, ovh

I purchased the server on ovh.com. (not gaming, regular)
For 3 days now I’ve been trying to set up protection against DDOS flood.
Nothing comes out. Support responds once a day and does not give an intelligent answer.
Therefore, I appeal to you.
How to configure a firewall to protect against DDoS attacks?

A server for the Rust game is installed on the server machine.
Port 10001 is open. If you launch an attack on this DDoS port using the UDP protocol, then ethernet is loaded up to 126 Mb / s and there are terrible lags on the server.
What am I doing wrong?

[firewall configuration screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKG4B.jpg)

Comment: does the flood comes to a specific port or generic and from how many hosts?

Comment: to 10001 port flood... 
100000+ requests in 30 sec

Comment: then hows about the host, how many?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, there's no effective way to defend a DDoS attack when it already hits your server and you have no physical access to this server. DDoS prevention requires filtering measures using firewall appliances connected upstream your server, by the provider, for example.

Comment: thats right if its not much hosts you can limit it by the firewall infront of the server. it may be possible to drop th via iptables but i aint think that will solve the problem